# Push Edit and Delete Options to the right most side possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Kindly have a look at this fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poddarrishabh/yLecK/1/).
You can notice the two symbols right next to the Text. How do I make the two symbols float to the rightmost side?

I have tried using `align`, `float` and `absolute` but nothing worked.

**NOTE:** In the actual program, the content is generated randomly using JavaScript, and a lot of content similar to this is generated continuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML contains an incorrect classname.

Replace `<span class=".toolbar">` with `<span class="toolbar">` and your `float: right` css will start working (absolute positioning is also an option).

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning the `toolbar` class incorrectly:

```
<span class=".toolbar">
```

should be

```
<span class="toolbar">
```

Then it works.